# Rails rspec GET request test for Grape index failed - returns empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-grape

I created an endpoint in grape which returns value (example below) which, after the entered `shop_code` returns some values as a JSON (swagger output below) - another app have to fetch this data. I test it in swagger and it works perfectly fine however my specs didn't worked and returns an error

> actual collection contained:    []

This is my first time when I'm using grape so first time when I have to write some test on it either.

`correct swagger output`

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "inquiry",
      "attributes": {
        "reference_id": 1,
        "post_code": "99312",
        "intended_use": "Other",
        "amount": 2000,
        "remaining_time": "2019-07-16"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`v1/controller/inquiries/data/index.rb`

```
class Index < Base
          params do
            requires :shop_code, type: String
          end

          helpers do
            def find_inquiries
              shop = Shop.find_by(code: params[:shop_code])
              Inquiry.joins(:shop_offers)
                     .where('shop_offers.shop_suggestion_id = ?', shop)
                     .includes(:process)
            end
          end

          get :export_data do
            skip_authorization

            ::Inquiries::DataSerializer.new(find_inquiries)
          end
```

**specs**

```
describe API::V1::Inquiries::Data::Index, type: :request do
  subject(:call) { get endpoint, params: params }
# tons of 'let' which are not the case in this example
  let(:endpoint) { "/api/v1/inquiries/data?shop_code=#{shop.code}" }
  let(:shop) { create(:shop, code: '10011001')}
  let(:params) { { shop_code: '10011001' } }

  describe 'data' do
    subject(:data) { json_response_body['data'] }

    let(:expected_data) do
      [
        {
          "id": inquiry.id,
          "type": 'inquiry',
          "attributes": {
            "reference_id": inquiry.id,
            "post_code": '33445',
            "intended_use": 'Other',
            "amount": 2000,
            "remaining_time": process.order_date
          }
        }
      ]
    end

    it 'returns expected value' do
      call
      expect(data).to match_array(expected_data)
    end
  end
end
```

I thought I've wrong URL in the `:endpoint` but swagger shows me this path for shop_code = 06671403 `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/inquiries/data?shop_code=06671403`

Comment: Check the rspec log, is the controller action receiving the right parameters? you have `shop_code=` on the URI and `{shop_code: ....}` on the params hash, maybe one is overriding the other. Is the request sopose to be GET or POST since you have parameters on the URI and the params, use one or the other to send the `shop_code` depending on what the api accepts.

Comment: @arieljuod I've create another let to pass code and result is the same. It's a  simple GET request, I don't see anything relevant in logs except what I wrote

Comment: Add some debugger on the controller action so you can inspect that the action is getting called and it's receiving the right parameters. Use byebug or pry to stop execution inside the controller.